# Server Side Include in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2

I want to include external webpage into my JSF 2.2 application using Server Side Includes. I wrote following code inside ui:define but nothing seems to be happening.

```
<!--#include virtual="https://example.com/path/to/page.php"-->
```

does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is not Server Side Include, as you want to embed a remote HTML rendering into your page.

You may consider that this remote page will need resources (CSS, Images, etc), which may conflict with your own embedding page.

The *best* way to achieve that is to use JSoup in a Backing Bean and to display the result with `h:outputText escape="false"`. But be careful with what you will display. You can offer a big security hole for your site or your users (XSS, CSRF, etc.). And you will still need to deal with remote resources ...

The real solution would be to use an `iframe` instead which will "solve" your problem pretty fast.

Comment: Could not agree more.